# How relevant is Timing Belt issue with BMW N43 engine?

Tags: engine, bmw, timing-belt

Are all BMW N43 engines bound to Timing Belt snapping issue? Or is it just matter of luck when the Engine is regularly serviced?

Comment: The issue is always relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The N43, like all newer BMW engines, has a timing chain, not a belt.

It appears that the issue could affect any of that generation of BMW engine, but regular servicing can reduce the risk - providing that you make sure that the chain tensioner is inspected every time, as it appears that this can stick and cause the failure.